# List of distinct items with their count based on another query iterating characters instead of values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a details page that brings in data from several tables. I want it to bring back the full list of a table and then segment out the list based on categories in a different section of the view. I have no problem bringing back the full list:

```
var query = string.Format("Select C.* from Cards C Left Join CardDecks CD ON CD.CardID = C.CardID Where DeckID = {0}", id);
            var cardlist = db.Cards.SqlQuery(query).ToList();
```

Which brings back something like Apple, Apple, Apple, Apple, Orange, Orange, Lime. When I try to section it out, I want something like:

- 4x Apples
- 2x Oranges
- 1x Lime etc.

  ```
          var creaturelist = " ";
          var list = creatures.Select(t => t.Title).ToList();
          var section = list.GroupBy(c => c, (a, b) => new { Title = a, Count = b.Count() });

          foreach (var item in section)
          {
              creaturelist = string.Format("{0}x {1}", item.Count, item.Title);
          }
      var vm = new ViewDeck();
      vm.Deck = deck;
      vm.CardList = cardlist;
      vm.Creatures = creaturelist;
      return View(vm);
  ```

My View Model:

```
public class ViewDeck
    {
        public Deck Deck { get; set; }
        public Card Cards { get; set; }
        public CardDeck CardDecks { get; set; }
        public IList<Card> CardList { get; set; }
        public dynamic Creatures { get; set; }
    }
```

Section of view having the issue:

```
CREATURES<br />
         @foreach (var item in Model.Creatures)
         {
            @Model.Creatures<br />
         }
```

The result I am in getting is repeating the last count plus title like 1x Lime repeated for as many characters exist in the title. I don't understand why it is running through each character of the title instead of just grabbing the whole value for title.

Comment: Obligatory warning about sql injection.  You should use parameters rather than formatting your query string.

Comment: Is SQL injection an issue if the tables being accessed do not contain user input values? Sorry, I have been trying to read up on security and there is a lot to learn.

Comment: For your query there is a very low chance since id is a numeric value.  But it's just a good habit to get into using parameters.  Also parameters take care of formatting that can easily be messed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define `Creatures` in your model as a list not a `string`, then generate the list by adding the items in the loop:

```
var creaturelist = new List<string>();
var list = creatures.Select(t => t.Title).ToList();
var section = list.GroupBy(c => c, (a, b) => new { Title = a, Count = b.Count() });

foreach (var item in section)
{
    creaturelist.Add(string.Format("{0}x {1}", item.Count, item.Title));
}
var vm = new ViewDeck();
vm.Deck = deck;
vm.CardList = cardlist;
vm.Creatures = creaturelist;
return View(vm);
```

and in the view

```
CREATURES<br />
@foreach (var item in Model.Creatures)
{
   @item<br />
}
```

you can make the list without loop:

```
var creaturelist = 
    list.GroupBy(c => c, (a, b) => string.Format("{0}x {1}", b.Count(), a)).ToList();
```